# How to upload image from HTML form using SFTP?

Tags: php, sftp, phpseclib

I'm having trouble uploading an image from an HTML form to SFTP server. I'm using phpseclib to achieve this.

```
<?php

    include('Net/SFTP.php');

    $uploaded_file = $_FILES["my_image"]["tmp_name"];

    $sftp = new Net_SFTP('my_server', 'my_port');
    if (!$sftp->login('my_username', 'my_pass')) {
        exit('Login Failed');
    }

    $sftp->mkdir('/home/new_dir');

    $sftp->put($uploaded_file,'/home/new_dir/'.$uploaded_file, ), NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE);

?>
```

The connection is there and I can create a directory successfully, therefore I assume that the problem is here:

```
$sftp->put($uploaded_file,'/home/new_dir/'.$uploaded_file, ), NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE);
```

Comment: du u get any error or is it just that the file does not appear on the server?

Comment: I don't get any error and the file does not appear on the server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/sftp/examples.html) the order of your arguments should be the other way round.

```
$sftp->put('/home/new_dir/'.$uploaded_file, $uploaded_file, NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE);
```

Comment: :-) No worries. Glad to have helped. Good luck with the rest of your project.